# How to create a ContainsDate typescript utility type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a utility type called `NonDate` that will convert any `T` into `never` if it encounters a Date object at any reasonable level of depth (ideally all levels but lets say 6 is reasonable)

```
type Test1 = NonDate<number>; // Result: number
type Test2 = NonDate<string>; // Result: string
type Test3 = NonDate<Date>; // Result: never
type Test4 = NonDate<boolean>; // Result: boolean
type Test5 = NonDate<Date[]>; // Result: never
type Test6 = NonDate<number[]>; // Result: number[]
type Test7 = NonDate<{}>; // Result: {}
type Test8 = NonDate<{ a: Date; b: string }>; // Result: never
type Test9 = NonDate<{ a: Date; b: number }>; // Result: never
type Test10 = NonDate<{ a: number; b: string }>; // Result: { a: number; b: string }
type Test11 = NonDate<{ a: { b: Date } }>; // Result: never
type Test12 = NonDate<{ a: string; b: string; test: Date[] }>; // Result: never
type Test13 = NonDate<{ a: string; b: string; test: number[] }>; // Result: { a: string; b: string; test: number[] }
```

I have tried a few different permutations

```
type HasDate<T> = T extends Date
  ? true
  : T extends Array<infer U>
  : HasDate<U>
  : T extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Date
        ? false
        : HasDate<T[K]>
    }[keyof T]
  : false

type HasDateDeep<T> = HasDate<T> extends true
  ? true
  : T extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]: HasDate<T[K]>
    }
  : T extends Array<infer U>
  ? HasDate<U>
  : false

type HasDateDeep1 = //... etc
```

Then mapping them all together w/

```
export type NonDate<T> = HasDate<T> extends true
  ? never
  : HasDateDeep<T> extends true
  ? never
  : HasDateDeep1<T> extends true
  //...etc
  : T
```

This mostly works but 1) its super verbose 2) it errors w/ circular types.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/weaDXw) meet your needs? (Please test thoroughly against expected use cases, these sorts of deeply nested types tend to have bizarre edge cases that require near-complete refactoring to fix.) If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Based on my initial testing it seems to work well! Thanks I will report back as I bang on it more.

Comment: Sadly this still can't handle circular types

```tsx
type CircularA = { value: CircularA, data: string }
type Test16 = NonDate<CircularA>; // Result: never
```

Error:
`Type of property 'value' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ [K in keyof CircularA]: NonDate<CircularA[K]>; }'.`

Not sure if there is a way to short circuit if the type is circular

Comment: Is that a requirement? Recursive utility types and recursive data types often play poorly together.   But if it’s a requirement please [edit] the relevant test cases into the question post.

Comment: This might work? Trying more now

```tsx
type NonDate<T, E = never> =
  T extends E ? T : T extends Date ? never :
  T extends object ? HasNeverToNever<{ [K in keyof T]: NonDate<T[K], E | T> }> : T;
```

But basically keep a running list of types we have checked and short circuit if we see it again.

[Example](https://tsplay.dev/mbaqoN)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to do with that example or why all your test cases have some `DisallowedSymbol` in there. Would you please [edit] the question with a test case you care about that fails? Not just in comments.  If you have your own answer you can of course post it, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to proceed when the question as asked has no test case demonstrating the problem you're having.

Comment: (continued) or do you mind if *I* [edit] with `CircularA` and `CircularB` from [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpAbXW) as examples?  And then does my suggestion meet your needs?  It uses an explicit depth limiter.  If that works for you I'll write up an answer, if not, let me know what's wrong and how you'd like me to proceed.

Comment: Updated the [link](https://tsplay.dev/WK358W) Your example mostly meets my needs I added two other edge cases i found

`{ test: any }` would result in `never` but should result in the type the fix is to check explicitly for `IsAny`

`{ test?: Date }` wouldn't trigger the fix is to make the type required. See example. Otherwise this seems to work well ty!

Comment: Since you haven't [edit]ed the question as I've asked multiple times, may I assume I can just post my original approach as an answer and then you will take steps offline as necessary to handle the edge cases you've raised in the comments? Some of the issues you're raising (circular types and `any`-detection) are edge cases for lots of types and therefore wider than I was imagining for a single SO question.  The one you've just raised about optional properties is more like what I was thinking, but again, this is not in the question itself, just another comment.